# Flutter - vector_math defined in Two Places

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Updated vector_math dependency to latest (2.1.0) in a flutter project and project now fails to build with error:

```
The argument type 'Vector2 (where Vector2 is defined in /mnt/data/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vector_math-2.1.0/lib/src/vector_math_64/vector2.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Vector2 (where Vector2 is defined in /mnt/data/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vector_math-2.1.0/lib/src/vector_math/vector2.dart)'. (Documentation)

Vector2 is defined in /mnt/data/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vector_math-2.1.0/lib/src/vector_math_64/vector2.dart (vector2.dart:10).
Vector2 is defined in /mnt/data/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vector_math-2.1.0/lib/src/vector_math/vector2.dart (vector2.dart:10).
```

How does one resolve this? Is this a flutter issue or is issue in vector_math package?

Comment: Which package was imported? Can you add the code where this is in use?

Comment: @RohanThacker there is no import of `vector_math` directly in the class which is errorring when making use of `Vector2`. But, the code is calling a function on another package of ours which is importing `'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart'`. If I update both (package class and calling class) to import `vector_math_64` then the error goes away. Your comment helped. If you put it as an answer then I can accept it and mark it as solved although I am not sure what the diff is between `vector_math.dart` and `vector_math_64.dart` and why there are two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the packages that were imported, the error is due to the the types being imported from different libraries.

`vector_math` and `vector_math_64` should be for `32bit` and `64bit` variants, they are implemented as two different libraries in the package. So you'd need to maintain consistency in how you the libraries are used.

A possible solution to not face this issue in the future is to export the types from a base package and import that types as needed from the base_package, this will protect users of the base_package from needing to know the what types are required or having this issue again.

For example:
lib/base_package.dart

```dart
export 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart'
or 
export 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart'
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing to

```
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart';
```

fixed it for me.

Another solution would be to scope it...

```
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as whatever;
```

Note, make sure you do it everywhere that you import!